# How to move a robot arm in a circle

Tags: trigonometry, robotics, kinematics

I have a 6 joint robot arm, and I want to move it in a circle. I want parameters to choose the radius, degrees, and resolution/quality of the circle.

How do I do this?

[image: arm]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### A quick trig review:

The hypotenuse is opposite the right angle of the triangle.

[image]

The ratio of the height to the hypotenuse is called the sine.

The ratio of the base to the hypotenuse is called the cosine.

### Generating (x,y) coordinates of a circle

The circle is centered at the point (0,0).
The radius of the circle is 1.
Angles are measured starting from the x-axis.
If we draw a line from the point (0,0) at an angle ***a*** from the x-axis, the line will intersect the circle at the point ***P***.

[image]

To generate the coordinates along a circle, let's start with a small example.
We'll use ***r*** to refer to the radius of the circle and ***a*** to refer to the angles spanned starting from the x-axis.

Let's start with just the five following angles: 0, 90, 180, 270 and 360.

(0 and 360 degrees are the same angle, which is on the positive x-axis).

```
r = 1

a = 0, 90, 180, 270, 360 (angles in degrees)
```

Then, to generate the X and y coordinates along the circle, we use the following equations for each of the angles:

```
x = r * cos(a)
y = r * sin(a)
```

These are the x and y coordinates calculated from the two equations above:

```
(1, 0)
(0, 1)
(-1, 0)
(0, -1)
(1,0)
```

Here's what that looks like on a graph:

[image]

In the above examples, we're only using 4 points, so it doesn't look much like a circle yet.
However, if we use 17 points, we can see the coordinates are approaching a circular shape:

[image]

### Here is a visualization of the math (sin cos wave):

[image: gif]

### Here is the Arduino code for a circular movement:

```
void moveCircle(float radius, float degrees, float resolution, bool direction)
{
  for (float i = 0; i <= degrees; i += resolution)
  {
    // Get X and Y
    float X = radius * cos(i * DEG_TO_RAD);
    float Y = radius * sin(i * DEG_TO_RAD);

    if (direction)
    {
      // Move circle vertically
      moveTz(X);
      moveTy(Y);
    }
    else
    {
      // Move circle horizontally
      moveTx(X);
      moveZ(Y);
    }
  }
}
```

I recommend testing this code by creating a graph in Microsoft Excel to verify that the x y coordinates create a circle.